# If $A$ and $B$ are finite sets, show $|A\cup B|= |A|+|B| \iff A\cap B = \emptyset$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> If $A$ and $B$ are finite sets, show $|A\cup B|= |A|+|B| \iff A\cap B = \emptyset$

I want to prove via the route: Let $A=\{a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n\}$  and $B=\{b_1,b_2,\dots ,b_m\}$ and then using the properties of sets to come to a conclusion.

Comment: Hint: $\lvert X \rvert = 0 \iff X = \emptyset$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First implication ($\Rightarrow$): $|A| = n$ and $|B| = m$ so $|A\cup B|=n+m$ which implies $a_i\neq b_j$ with $1\leq i\leq n$ and $1\leq j\leq m$. If no $a_i=b_j$ then the intersection of *A* and *B* is the nullset.

Second implication ($\Leftarrow$): Suppose $A\cap B=\emptyset $ then there is no element that is in both $A$ and $B$ (the sets are incomparable). So $A={a_1,a_2,…,a_n}$ and $B={b_1,b_2,…,b_m}$ then $|A|+|B|=n+m=|A\cup B|$

Comment: Thanks a lot! Can we prove it by contradiction?

Comment: Yes! Think about what the contrapositive of each implication would be

Answer (score 0):

Let's prove it with characteristic functions. Consider the function
$$
f(x) =  \chi_A(x) + \chi_B(x) - \chi_{A\cup B}(x).
$$
Say $y \in A\cap B$. Then we compute
$$
f(y) = \chi_A(y) + \chi_B(y) - \chi_{A\cup B}(y) = 1 + 1 - 1 = 1.
$$
Next suppose $y \in A\cup B$ but $y\notin A \cap B$. Then without loss of generality, say $y\in A\setminus B$. Now we compute
$$
f(y) = \chi_A(y) + \chi_B(y) - \chi_{A\cup B}(y) = 1 + 0 - 1 = 0.
$$
Therefore $f(x) = \chi_{A\cap B}(x)$. To get the desired identity, sum over all the elements of $A\cup B$ to get
\begin{align*}
\sum_{x}{\chi_A(x) + \chi_B(x) - \chi_{A\cup B}(x)} &= \sum_{x}{\chi_{A\cap B}(x)}\\
|A| + |B| - |A\cap B| &= |A \cup B|.
\end{align*}
As stated, this proof only applies to finite sets, which seems like a limitation. However, this proof adapts naturally to measurable sets in a measure space, replacing the sum by the relevant integral.